# Adding new key, values to dictionaries within a list from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Task : I have to generate some random date of births and add it to my list of three dictionaries.

I have generated the random task but I am stuck with adding 'date of birth' keys to the dictionaries inside ducks with values from the list that I created. Any suggestions please?
This is the code I have so far:

```
ducks =[{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 
  'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 
  'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 
  'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}] #list with three dictionaries
import random
dob = []
def dateofbirth(number=1):
    Year = random.randrange(1990, 2010)
    for item in range(number):
        yield random.randrange(1990, 2010), random.randrange(1, 12), random.randrange(1, 30)

dateTimeThatIwant = dateofbirth(3)
#print(dateTimeThatIwant)

for year, month, date in dateTimeThatIwant:
    #print((year, month, date))
    dob.append([year, month, date])
print(dob)
for d in ducks:
    d["dob"] = dob_value
```

Comment: Removed the `random` tag since you stated you'd already completed the random part.

Comment: You posted this during my class. You could just ask me, your teacher in the class, rather than pasting the class exercise on Stack Overflow. I will remind you about the warning given to the class two days ago about academic unfair means and the possible consequences for not attributing your source citation. The Stack Overflow terms of use will require you to cite your sources from here also. Thank You.

Comment: (1/2) Hi Brian, with due respect, firstly I didn't use this code for the exercise because I wanted to learn how to iterate inside a function. Secondly, I didn't get the required help inside the lab that's why I came here. I feel like most of the demonstrators treat us like professional coder.

Comment: (2/2) My understanding is that these exercises are for practise to learn basics, I didn't knew that it is wrong to get outside help if you cant get figure it out.  But reading your comment makes me realise that it was wrong of me share the class data (ducks) in public, next time i will keep it in mind if i wanted to learn something at least make an effort to make a dummy data. I hope it clears my actions here, thank you.

Comment: If you have problems with the answer from a teaching assistant you can go to the class teacher. We are all there for you to speak to. If every one of the many hundreds of student in this class posted questions that could easily be answered in class Stack Overflow would become overwhelmed with "Homework" questions. You may find this FAQ useful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `zip` to iterate over both containers. It will allow you to take both iterables and return it as a tuple. Those values can simply be used in a normal for loop. You should note that this assumes both `ducks` and `dob` have the same size.

```
ducks =[{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 
  'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 
  'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 
  'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}] #list with three dictionaries
import random
dob = []
def dateofbirth(number=1):
    Year = random.randrange(1990, 2010)
    for item in range(number):
        yield random.randrange(1990, 2010), random.randrange(1, 12), random.randrange(1, 30)

dateTimeThatIwant = dateofbirth(3)
#print(dateTimeThatIwant)

for year, month, date in dateTimeThatIwant:
    #print((year, month, date))
    dob.append([year, month, date])
print(dob)
for c_dob, d in zip(dob, ducks):
    d['dob'] = c_dob
```

Comment: You don't really need a generator for this. It adds no value. Also, note that your *dateofbirth* function could return an invalid date which could potentially cause problems elsewhere in your code (not shown here)

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of a generator and allowing for the *ducks* list being any length and with an pseudo-random date of birth generator that will only produce valid dates, you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

ducks = [{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120,
          'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None},
         {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123,
          'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None},
         {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1,
          'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}]


def randomdate(loyear=1990, hiyear=2010):
    while True:
        try:
            yy = randint(loyear, hiyear)
            mm = randint(1, 12)
            dd = randint(1, 31)
            datetime.strptime(f'{dd}/{mm}/{yy}', '%d/%m/%Y')
            return [yy, mm, dd]
        except ValueError:
            pass


for duck in ducks:
    duck['dob'] = randomdate()

print(ducks)
```

In the unlikely event that the random selection of year, month and day creates something invalid, datetime.strptime will raise ValueError so we just try again

Comment: thank you so much. what if i wanted to edit the dates more like mm ={mm:02d} and dates looks like this mm/dd/yy in the current code it looks like mm,dd,yy

Comment: In your original code you were adding the date as a list comprising the day, month and year. That's what this does.

Answer (score -1):

```
ducks =[{'first_name': 'Davey', 'last_name': 'McDuck', 'location': "Rob's Office", 'insane': True, 'followers': 12865, 'following': 120, 
  'weapons': ['wit', 'steely stare', 'devilish good looks'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Jim', 'last_name': 'Bob', 'location': 'Turing Lab', 'insane': False, 'followers': 123, 
  'following': 5000, 'weapons': ['squeak'], 'remorse': None}, 
 {'first_name': 'Celest', 'last_name': '', 'location': 'Throne Room', 'insane': True, 'followers': 40189, 'following': 1, 
  'weapons': ['politics', 'dance moves', 'chess grandmaster', 'immortality']}] #list with three dictionaries
import random
dob = []
def dateofbirth(number=1):
    Year = random.randrange(1990, 2010)
    for item in range(number):
        yield random.randrange(1990, 2010), random.randrange(1, 12), random.randrange(1, 30)

dateTimeThatIwant = dateofbirth(3)
#print(dateTimeThatIwant)

for year, month, date in dateTimeThatIwant:
    #print((year, month, date))
    dob.append([year, month, date])
print(dob)
for i,d in enumerate(ducks):
    d["dob"]=d.get("dob",dob[i])
```

Comment: This would be much more useful if you specified the change that you made to his code. It probably isn't necessary to include all the code, just the part you changed and an explanation.